# Remove launch options from SDDM other than Plasma

Tags: kde, sddm

I installed Kodi (Arch Linux KDE) and it inserted an option in SDDM to login directly to Kodi instead of logging in to Plasma as normal. How do I remove this?

I see nothing relevant listed in /etc/sddm and /etc/sddm.d/ doesn't exist.

cat /etc/sddm.conf:

```
[Autologin]
Relogin=false
Session=
User=

[General]
HaltCommand=
RebootCommand=

[Theme]
Current=breeze
CursorTheme=
```

Comment: Look in `/usr/share/xsessions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These options are usually not configured per-DM, but in a common location for all DMs. The usual place is `/usr/share/xsessions`, where `.desktop` files will be present for each login option. Per-DM, additional lookup locations may also be specified, but `/usr/share/xsessions` is a good starting point when looking for the `.desktop` file of a particular option.